# Merge data where 1 column row the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

Current data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Tmp') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #Tmp
END
create table #Tmp (MasterID int,TableDataOrder int,Idea varchar(50),Feasibility varchar(50),BusinessReview varchar(50)
                    ,Concept varchar(50),DetailedDesign varchar(50),TestValidation varchar(50),ManufacturingProductIntegration varchar(50)
                    ,ProductSales varchar(50))
insert into #Tmp
select 26,1,NULL,'02',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
insert into #Tmp
select 26,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,'04',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
insert into #Tmp
select 26,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'05',NULL,NULL,NULL
insert into #Tmp
select 26,2,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'05',NULL,NULL,NULL
insert into #Tmp
select 26,3,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'05',NULL,NULL,NULL
insert into #Tmp
select 26,4,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'05',NULL,NULL,NULL

select * from  #Tmp
```

Current Result:

[image: CurrentResult]

Expected Result:

[image: ExpectedResult]

How to merge the data where TableDataOrder is the same?

Comment: What is your attempt? Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
select
    MasterID
    , TableDataOrder
    , max(Idea) Idea
    , max(Feasibility) Feasibility
    , max(BusinessReview) BusinessReview
    , max(Concept) Concept
    , max(DetailedDesign) DetailedDesign
    , max(TestValidation) TestValidation
    , max(ManufacturingProductIntegration) ManufacturingProductIntegration
    , max(ProductSales) ProductSales

from #Tmp

group by MasterID
    ,TableDataOrder;
```

It does not matter `avg()` or `min()` or `max()` or else.
But pay attention, if `Feasibility` has been written twice with different value for same `TableDataOrder` it will not work.

Comment: The data itself is made up using a pivot, and the TableDataOrder is a rowNumber partitioned by each of the pivoted columns, so I don't think it would ever have the same TableDataorder, so this is perfect for what I am trying to achieve. Thank you for your help!